# $\lim_{x\to\infty}{1-\Phi(x)\over \phi(x)/x}=1$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, density-function

I have to prove the following:

> Let $\phi$ and $\Phi$ denote the standard normal density and distribution functions respectively. Prove that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{1-\Phi(x)\over \phi(x)/x}=1$$

I am not able to start. $\Phi$ is $\int \phi(x)dx$. How can I calculate the limit **without L'Hopital's rule**?

Comment: Did you try L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @Qwerty; why? 'x'?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. I'm not sure it will even work but this is a case with a $0/0$ thing going on, which makes me immediately think of L'Hopital's rule. Differentiate both the numerator and denominator with respect to $x$ and see if the limit of that ratio is 1.

Comment: lol at this edit. What's wrong with LR??

Comment: @not_bonferroni For sake of knowedge. A question is not just to solve and be left alone!

Comment: If that's the case, then perhaps you can motivate the question a little bit. This basically feels like a homework question to me, in which case something like takin' it to the Hospital is the natural answer.

Comment: Perhaps there is another way, but the only way I can see this problem being solvable is to show the rate of change in the denominator is the same as the rate of change in the numerator as $x$ approaches infinity (since the ratio isn't constant).  So, you are probably going to either have to use L'hopital's rule, or a hand wavy way of doing L'hopital's rule without calling it such.

Comment: You are computing the limit of $$x\int_x^\infty \frac{\phi(t)}{\phi(x)}\,dt.$$  Approximate $\phi(t)/\phi(x)=\exp((x^2-t^2)/2)$ as $\exp(-x(t-x))$ and do the integral explicitly.  (A rigorous proof uses a two-epsilon argument: the approximation is excellent for small positive values of $t-x$ and you can cut off the integration for higher values.)  This at least is more insightful than l'Hopital's Rule, even if less automatic. cc @Jonathan

Comment: @whuber This is too high level for me to understand directly. Can you please give me a proof of the interesting fact you claimed?(or a reference)

Comment: My comment is actually more elementary than the original question: it requires knowing only the definitions of $\phi$ and $\Phi$ and the linearity of the integral.

Comment: @whuber You are approximating one $t$ by $x$ because of their small difference, and higher values are to be neglected as $e^{-\text{ large quantity}}\to 0$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  Although it's not as elegant as Dilip's solution, it is interesting to graph the original function $t\to\phi(t)/\phi(x)$ and its approximation: for $t\ge x$, they draw so close together by the time $x=8$ or so that they are indistinguishable.  In words: relative to the height of $\phi$ at the value $x$, the function $t\to\phi(t)$ behaves exponentially for $t$ slightly larger than $x$ up until the point (around $t=x+4/x$ or so) that it is indistinguishable from zero.

Comment: @whuber  You can't compare elegance like that! your idea is much more visual and intuitive(and real-analytically speaking, works perfectly) than Dilip's solution. What more do you need for **elegance**?

Comment: Qwerty, if you are looking for real elegance, compare stats.SE Moderator whuber's approach here to the approach used in stats.SE Moderator cardinal's [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/28754/15941) to the [same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28751/15941)  that I had answered on math.SE

Comment: @DilipSarwate I know this is an absolute digression, but still I will ask: Is there some sort of compilation of "Elegant answers" to different questions compiled together here? (IF you know about **Proofs from THE BOOK**, you will understand what I mean, although the compilation might not be only _proofs_ !) OR should I ask on meta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $x>0$, write $1-\Phi(x)=Q(x)$ as $$\int_x^\infty \phi(t) dt = \int_x^\infty t^{-1}\cdot t \phi(t) dt$$ and then integrate by parts. You will get that $Q(x)$ is smaller than $\frac{\phi(x)}{x}$ by a term which converges to $0$ as $x\to \infty$. The details can be found in [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69417/15941) on
math.SE. In fact, if you read than answer all the way to the bitter end,
you will
see that I showed (via integration by parts again!) that for $x > 0$,
$$\left.\left.\frac{\phi(x)}{x}
\right(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)< Q(x) < \frac{\phi(x)}{x}.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: How does ${\phi(x)\over x} $ come? It doesnot by partial integration... What am I missing?

Comment: Did you notice that the antiderivative of $t\phi(t)$ is $-\phi(t)$? Did you forget to use the limits?

Comment: OOps. Silly of me.. Got the answer. Thanks for the new approach.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\frac{1-\Phi\left(x\right)}{\phi\left(x\right)}=\frac{1}{\lambda\left(-x\right)}$$
where
$$\lambda\left(x\right)=\frac{\phi\left(x\right)}{\Phi\left(x\right)}$$ is the inverse-Mill's ratio. It has the properties that $$\lambda\left(-x\right)>x;$$ $$0\le\lambda'\left(x\right)\le-1.$$ So $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-\Phi\left(x\right)}{\phi\left(x\right)/x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{\lambda\left(-x\right)}$$ Applying L'hospitals rule yields $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda'\left(-x\right)}.$$ It's known that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\lambda'\left(-x\right)=1.$$